# Ember Data 1.0.0: how to retrieve validation errors (422 response)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am converting from Ember data 0.13 to 1.0.0 Beta 1.  In 0.13, I was using the becameError and becameInvalid states to know whether there was a problem when saving a record.

In 1.0.0 there is no longer a transaction and you need to use the save promise to handle errors.  See below:

```
 save: function() {
    this.get('model').save().then(function () {
        alert("Record saved");
      }, function () {
        alert("Problem");
      });
    },
```

In the above, I want to make a distinction between validation errors and all the rest (just as it was before in 0.13 with becameError and becameInvalid).

Is there a way to access the error object and how to read the validation errors included in the json response ?  Before this was via this.get('content.errors') ...

Hoep somebody can help
Marc

Answer (score 2):

Three steps:

Return errors in a proper format. If it Rails application, then:

```
\# Rails controller, update function

format.json { render json: {errors: @post.errors.messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

Set errors in promise

```
// app.js
save: function() {
  self = this;
  this.get('model').save().then(function () {
    alert("Record saved");
  }, function (response) {
    self.set('errors', response.responseJSON.errors);
  });
}
```

Display errors in a handlebar template

```
<\!-- index.html -->
{{input type="text" value=title}}<span class="alert-error">{{errors.title}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you substitute the `bacameInvalid` and `becameError` since states are now being removed, but you could try this as a catchall workaround:

```
Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', function(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  console.log(error.stack);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There seems to be an error object in the promise and you can access the properties via error.status (e.g. 422) and error.responseText.  using an alert in teh promise works, but using for example this.transitionToRoute('authors.index'); in the success part of the promise or this.set('validationErrors', error.responseText); in the error part of the promise does not work.  It looks like the word "this" cannot be used inside a promise ...

Comment: @cyclomarc, what if you save a reference to `this` like `var self = this;` outside the promise and use `self` inside, do you have then access?

Comment: Yes, this works.  I am always confused with the "this" ...  Thx.  Now I can continue trying to implement a decent error handling when saving records in Ember data 1.0.0